# PHP Gives "-0" As Answer From Division

Tags: php

I have a fairly complicated script that uses randomly generated numbers.  Every so often, "-0" will be the answer to some kind of division problem.  Most recently, it was `0 ÷ -198 = -0`.

When I try to recreate that and echo the answer, it comes out as just 0 (as it should).  My script doesn't always do with when dividing with negative numbers, BTW.  I ran it another time and `0 ÷ -27 = 0` came up.

Basically, I'm getting `$b` and `$a` from other areas in the script and then doing this...

`$sol_1 = $b / $a;`

and `$sol_1` occasionally ends up being -0.

Any ideas about what could cause this kind of behavior?

Comment: What version of php are you using?

Comment: @Anigel: I'm actually using WAMP server on my local machine and it's 5.5.12.